Running Elasticsearch and OpenSearch on Docker-compose
I have the following docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - http.port=9201
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - "9201:9201"
      - "9300:9300"
    expose:
      - "9201"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9201/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - elastic
    command: >
      bash -c '
        until curl -sS "http://localhost:9201/_cat/health?h=status" | grep -q "green\|yellow"; do
          sleep 1
        done
        curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9201/products" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
        {
          "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 1,
            "analysis": {
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          },
          "mappings": {
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "author": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "published_date": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "purchase_url": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }'
      '
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2GB
  opensearch-node1A:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node1A
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1A
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2A:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node2A
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2A
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboardsA:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.1.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboardsA
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1A:9200","https://opensearch-node2A:9200"]'
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  logstash-with-plugin:
    image: opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash-with-plugin
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
    driver: bridge
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

I want to do a POC about transferring data from Elasticsearch to Opensearch, but I want them running over containers with docker-compose.yml.
So I set Elasticsearch to run on port 9201 while Opensearch runs on port 9200.
However, from the logs, I see that the Elasticsearch container fails to to start:
logstash-with-plugin    | [2024-09-26T04:29:39,365][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.32}
logstash-with-plugin    | [2024-09-26T04:29:39,376][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ][main] Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"}
logstash-with-plugin    | [2024-09-26T04:29:39,384][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
logstash-with-plugin    | [2024-09-26T04:29:39,413][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
logstash-with-plugin    | [2024-09-26T04:29:39,418][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main][0710cad67e8f47667bc7612580d5b91f691dd8262a4187d9eca8cf87229d04aa] Starting server on port: 5044
elasticsearch           | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9201: Connection refused
elasticsearch           | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9201: Connection refused
elasticsearch           | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9201: Connection refused
elasticsearch           | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9201: Connection refused
elasticsearch           | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9201: Connection refused

How can I have both running ?

The commands in command will override the startup command in elasticsearch image, so elasticsearch service will not start.

In elasticsearch service section you have to remove command part and create products index manually or you can use docker compose file below:
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - http.port=9201
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - "9201:9201"
      - "9300:9300"
    expose:
      - "9201"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9201/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - elastic
    command: >
      bash -c '
        /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh &
        until [ "$(curl -sS "http://localhost:9201/_cat/health?h=status" 2>&1 | grep "green")" = "green" ]; do
          echo "Status is not green, retrying..."
          sleep 1
        done
        echo "Status is green"
        curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9201/products" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"settings\":{\"number_of_shards\":1,\"number_of_replicas\":1,\"analysis\":{\"analyzer\":\"standard\"}},\"mappings\":{\"properties\":{\"title\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"analyzer\":\"standard\"},\"author\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"analyzer\":\"standard\"},\"description\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"analyzer\":\"standard\"},\"published_date\":{\"type\":\"date\"},\"purchase_url\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}}}"
        exec tail -f /dev/null
      '
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2GB

  opensearch-node1A:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node1A
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1A
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2A:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node2A
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2A
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboardsA:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.1.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboardsA
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1A:9200","https://opensearch-node2A:9200"]'
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  logstash-with-plugin:
    image: opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash-with-plugin
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
    driver: bridge
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

In the above docker compose file, I just edited the command section of the elasticsearch service to match.
